Error while sending POST request on Postman
While sending the post request on postman, I am getting the error: review validation failed: audiobookId: Path audiobookId is required., userId: Path userId is required.

I have also added the authorization token,
below is the server side code:
Review schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const review = new mongoose.Schema({
    audiobookId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "audiobook",
        required: true,
    },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
        required: true,
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        default: 0,
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    }
},{timestamps:true});

module.exports = mongoose.model("review", review);

Review Route
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { submitReview } = require('../controllers/review');
const {authenticateToken} = require("./userAuth");

// Route to submit a review
router.post('/:id', authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const review = await submitReview(req.audiobookId, req.userId, req.body);
        console.log("success review post");
        res.status(201).json(review);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
        console.log(("error review post"));
    }
});

module.exports = router;

Review controller
const Review = require('../models/review');
const Audiobook = require('../models/audiobook');
const submitReview = async (audiobookId, userId, reviewData) => {
    // Check if the user has already submitted a review
    const existingReview = await Review.findOne({ audiobookId, userId });

    if (existingReview) {
        // Update the existing review
        await Review.updateOne(
            { _id: existingReview._id },
            { $set: reviewData }
        );

        // update audiobook with new average rating and review count
        await updateAudiobookRating(audiobookId);

        return existingReview;
    } else {
        // Create a new review
        const newReview = new Review({
            audiobookId: audiobookId,
            userId: userId,
            rating: reviewData.rating,
            comment: reviewData.comment,
            createdAt: reviewData.createdAt,
        });
        await newReview.save();

        // update audiobook with average rating and review count
        await updateAudiobookRating(audiobookId);

        return newReview;
    }
};
const updateAudiobookRating = async (audiobookId) => {
    const reviews = await Review.find({ audiobookId });
    const averageRating = reviews.reduce((sum, r) => sum + r.rating, 0) / reviews.length;
    await Audiobook.updateOne(
        { _id: audiobookId },
        { $set: { averageRating: averageRating, reviewsCount: reviews.length } }
    );
};

module.exports = { submitReview };


Inside router.post('/:id') just change req.audiobookId and req.userId to req.body.audiobookId and req.body.userId

router.post('/:id', authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const review = await submitReview(req.audiobookId, req.userId, req.body);
    console.log("success review post");
    res.status(201).json(review);
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
    console.log(("error review post"));
}
});

While calling submit review function, access values from req.body.
req.audiobookId -> req.body.audiobookId
req.userId -> req.body.userId,
